# Closing other tabs in terminal on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, ssh, iterm

I am using iTerm2, but I wouldn't mind switching back to the original terminal for just this feature.

I open hundreds of SSH tabs every day and often end up working after a while only working on 1 terminal and other SSH tabs don't really matter anymore. In the browser at least you have "closer other tabs", "close left tabs", "close right tabs".

Is there any way to have a "close other tabs" in a Mac OS X terminal?

Comment: Is this question the right way round? On my machine standard terminal has Close Other Tabs, while iTerm2 does not. Which version of OS X are you running?

Comment: Which OSX version do You have? On my Terminal there's a function "Close other tabs" when I right click on the tab.

Comment: There's even a shortcut for this: ⌘⌥W

Comment: Ahh right! My standard terminal has the feature, iTerm2 unfortunately does not, right! I run Mac OS X 10.9.4.

Answer (score 1):

As a work around, you can drag the tab you want to keep to a different window, then close the first window with the extraneous tabs and they are all gone with one click.

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned in the question comments, this is not possible in iTerm 2. It is possible in the built-in Terminal.app, but that was not the question.

While this isn't an optimal solution, [a script has been written to implement this in iTerm](https://coderwall.com/p/fe-wzg). I did not write the script nor have I tested it, so I cannot verify the effectiveness of this solution. You may be able to bind a different keyboard shortcut to this script to satisfy your requirements.

[iTerm issue report and script source](https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=1944).

Comment: I tried it and unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Well, I tried! I'll keep looking, but it appears that the iTerm development team needs to add this functionality in.